# What's the time unit in /proc/lock_stat output

Tags: debug

What is the time unit in the lock stat output from /proc/lock_stat? microsecond or nanosecond?

```
class name    con-bounces    contentions   waittime-min   waittime-max waittime-total    acq-bounces   acquisitions   holdtime-min   holdtime-max holdtime-total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
&(&dentry->d_lock)->rlock:       2917691        3323806           0.10      157427.70  2221545741.66        8786458       19485395           0.00         235.65    38647798.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buried in [the documentation](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.4/Documentation/lockstat.txt) is the following line:

> The integer part of the time values is in us.

So those values are in microseconds.